# currentAdvice.adviceInstruction returning strange results

Tags: ios, skmaps

On IOS, I am using the delegate method:\

```
func routingService(routingService: SKRoutingService!, didChangeCurrentAdvice currentAdvice: SKRouteAdvice!, isLastAdvice: Bool) {
    print("adviceInstruction")
    print(currentAdvice.adviceInstruction)
    delegate?.didChangeCurrentAdvice(currentAdvice.adviceInstruction)
}
```

The currentAdvice.adviceInstruction when running in simulator mode, returns strange instructions when it lists distances, like:

```
in 200 50  yards turn right
```

I want to be able to state in my app, where you are turning and in how far. So I would expected something like in 50 yard turn right. Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Have you checked the demo project-there you should find an example: http://developer.skobbler.com/support#download

Comment: Yes i did actually use the sample code to test thats where i got it from and used the delegate method they used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this](http://sdkblog.skobbler.com/advisor-support-text-to-speech-scout-audio/) article for context.

If you want "human readable" text instructions, use the TTS option for audio advices: http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/ios#sec24